# How to create a common API class for getting common response in flutter using riverpod

Tags: flutter

I want to create a common API class so I can call that API class for every API and get data.

I have tried but failed to get common response from API class. So now I am here to get some help from my stackoverflow team.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Create a file called `api_service.dart`.

Inside `api_service.dart`, import the necessary packages:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
```

Create a class called ApiService that will contain the common API methods:

```
class ApiService {
  static const String baseUrl = 'https://api.domain.com'; // Replace with your API base URL

  // methods here
}
```

Below is full `api_service.dart` code:

```
class ApiService {
  static const String baseUrl = 'https://api.example.com'; // Replace with your API base URL

  static Future<dynamic> get(String endpoint) async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('$baseUrl/$endpoint'));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return json.decode(response.body);
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load data');
    }
  }
}
```

How to use:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'api_service.dart';

void fetchData() async {
  try {
    final data = await ApiService.get('users'); // Replace 'users' with your desired API endpoint
    print('API response: $data');
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error fetching data: $e');
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import'package:windexprcticalusing_riverpod/application/dialog/dialod_service.dart';
import 'package:windexprcticalusing_riverpod/utils/appcolors.dart';

class ApiClient {
ApiClient();

Map<String, String> createHeaders() {
 final headers = <String, String>{
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  };

return headers;
}

Future<T?> postData<T>({
required Uri uri,
required var headers,
required var body,
required T Function(dynamic data) builder,
}) async {
try {
  print("_postData URL=-=-=-=-::: $uri");
  print("_postData headers=-=-=-=-::: $headers");
  print("_postData body=-=-=-=-::: $body");
  var request = http.Request('POST', uri);
  request.body = json.encode(body);
  print('_postData $uri body ${request.body}');
  request.headers.addAll(headers);

  http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();
  final responseString = await response.stream.bytesToString();

  String newwresponse = responseString.replaceAll('{"d":null}', '');
  if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201) {
    print('response.statusCode is ${response.statusCode}');

    log("response is=-=- ${responseString}");
    return builder(newwresponse);
  } else {
    DialogServiceV1().showSnackBar(
        content: response.reasonPhrase.toString(),
        color: AppColors.appprimarycolor.withOpacity(0.7),
        textclr: AppColors.white);
    print(response.reasonPhrase);
    return null;
  }
} catch (e) {
  DialogServiceV1().showSnackBar(
      content: e.toString(),
      color: AppColors.appprimarycolor.withOpacity(0.7),
      textclr: AppColors.white);
  throw Exception("Exception is =-=-1 $e");
}
}

Future<T?> multipartData<T>({
required Uri uri,
required var headers,
required var body,
required T Function(dynamic data) builder,
required var imageparam,
required var imagepath,
}) async {
try {
  print("_multipartData URL=-=-=-=-::: $uri");
  print("_multipartData headers=-=-=-=-::: $headers");
  print("_multipartData body=-=-=-=-::: $body");
  var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri);
  request.fields.addAll(body);
  print('_multipartData $uri body ${request.fields}');
  request.files
      .add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(imageparam, imagepath));
  request.headers.addAll(headers);

  http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();
  if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201) {
    print('response.statusCode is ${response.statusCode}');
    final responseString = await response.stream.bytesToString();
    log("response is=-=-${responseString}");
    return builder(responseString);
  } else {
    print(response.reasonPhrase);
    return null;
  }
} catch (e) {
  DialogServiceV1().showSnackBar(
      content: e.toString(),
      color: AppColors.red.withOpacity(0.7),
      textclr: AppColors.white);
  throw Exception("Exception is =-=-2 $e");
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Is this meant as an answer? Or are you providing code to illustrate what you've tried, but which isn't working? If the former, do remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?